# Passing arguments to Spring AOP advice causes exception at runtime

Tags: spring-aop, aspect

I am trying to apply advice on my Spring REST Controllers so I have provided `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in `@Configuration` and included package of `@Aspect` annotated class in `@ComponentScan`.

Things are working with following code.

```
 @Pointcut("execution(* com.abc.api..controller.*.*(..))")
     public static void controllers() {
 }

 @Before("controllers()")
 public void startLogging() {
      System.out.println("Here we go.");
 }
```

Controller methods are receiving `HttpSession` as first argument. I want to get that session in advice. So I tried following.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.abc.api..controller.*.*(..))")
public static void controllers() {}

@Pointcut("controllers() && args(session) ")
public static void sessionedController(HttpSession session) {}

@Before("sessionedController(session)")
public void startLogging(HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("Here we are");
}
```

But this causes following exception at startup.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1966)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15AnnotationFinder.getParameterNamesFromLVT(Java15AnnotationFinder.java:311)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15AnnotationFinder.getParameterNames(Java15AnnotationFinder.java:293)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.tryToDiscoverParameterNames(Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.java:325)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.getDeclaredPointcuts(Java15ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegate.java:296)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredPointcuts(ReferenceType.java:884)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$PointcutGetter.get(ResolvedType.java:243)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$PointcutGetter.get(ResolvedType.java:241)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4$1.hasNext(Iterators.java:213)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4.hasNext(Iterators.java:230)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.findPointcut(ResolvedType.java:743)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ReferencePointcut.resolveBindings(ReferencePointcut.java:148)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.resolve(Pointcut.java:189)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.resolvePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:313)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:294)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:170)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:194)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:248)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:280)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 24 more
```

I don't know why this is failing and how to resolve the issue. I have also looked into [these docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing) but failed to find anything.

Please guide me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

`@Pointcut` methods were static. Removing it removed the curse. So corrected state is provided below.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.abc.api..controller.*.*(..))")
public void controllers() {}

@Pointcut("controllers() && args(session,..) ")
public void sessionedController(HttpSession session) {}

@Before("sessionedController(session)")
public void startLogging(HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("Here we are");
}
```

Though I have also updated `args(session,..)` in the answer, this was not actual culprit. Even this was not working with static method.